Why Angular 17 Routing do not Recognise 'caPitals' in Routing Path?
In a app-routing.module.ts in the route path below:
    const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {path:'home',component: SelectComponent},
    {path: 'myForm', component: FormComponentComponent}
    ];

The path- {path: 'myForm', component: FormComponentComponent} wont work but if you change 'myForm' to 'myform' the routes works as expected.
Why the presence of capiTal prevent the routes to function??
Try: 'localhost:4200/myForm' it doesnt work while 'localhost:4200/myform' it works perfectly!!

The DefaultUrlSerializer is case sensitive.
If you want a case insensitive serializer you'll have to implement and provide your own UrlSerializer.

Well that is may be another option to avoid similar problem! I have been looking for solutions to why my page wont respond if I have ever used caPital in my routes. Because I dont want another fellow out there to fall in the same pot or I dont want to wast time another day on the similar scenario. Just try 'localhost:4200/myHome' while on the routes path '{path: 'myHome', component: AppComponent}' and 'localhost:4200/myhome' while on the routes path '{path: 'myhome', component: AppComponent}'  The one with myHome wont open the page while with myhome it works! Whyyyyy!
